# Почему не обновляется изображение в Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Я только начал изучать модуль Pygame. Решил делать интерфейс часов. Сделал стрелку секунд и по логике она должна менять угол с изменением секунд. Но она застывает на первой секунде и не меняется. Код прилагаю ниже.

```
import pygame
import time

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 360
FPS = 30

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BROWN = (150, 75, 0)

seconds = time.time()
local_time = time.localtime(seconds)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.flip()

startpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(240, 180)
endpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(30, 90)
angle = 0

pygame.display.set_caption("Clock")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.draw.circle(screen, BROWN, (240, 180), 100, 2)



running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # проверить закрытие окна
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    angle = local_time.tm_sec * 6
    current_endpoint = startpoint + endpoint.rotate(angle)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, startpoint, current_endpoint, 2)

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(30)  



pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Вы внутри цикла не обновляете local_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angle = time.localtime(time.time()).tm_sec * 6
```